# PDF attachments are corrupted after file decoding

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, decoding

There I have code that decodes all attachments in my mail:

`for (String key : attachments.keySet()) {
      String fileContent = attachments.get(key);
      attachments.put(key, getEncodedPartFromAttachment(fileContent));
}`

`private String decodeFileContent(String encodedData) {
      return new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedData));
}`

After encoding and decoding back, I faced some issues, like:

Original PDF: %âãÏÓ

Transformed PDF: %����

Original PDF: H‰d;1D¯2'°l'Î§¥¡¢@²Ü¿À†XØ&Ò›ÌG~€Épõ·

Transformed PDF: H�d�;1D�2'�l'Χ���@��ܿ���X�&қ�G~��p��

Is there some way not to corrupt content while encoding-decoding?

Comment: PDF files are binary files. You force the binary data into a string: `new String (...)`. This damages the binary PDF data,  depending on the used encoding even beyond repair. Handle binary attachments as binaries instead,  e.g. as `byte []` or as `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF files are binary files; they in particular can contain arbitrary byte sequences.

You force the binary data into a string:

```
return new String(...);
```

Depending on the encoding given or assumed in that transformation, this damages the binary PDF data, probably even beyond repair.

Thus, please handle binary attachments as binaries instead, e.g. as `byte[]` or as `ByteBuffer`.